# Implementing drainage ditch in QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope

In QGIS, I am trying to simulate some measures against erosion. One measure would be to install a drainage ditch at a contour line, where the slope goes from e.g. >30% to <30%. What I've tried so far:

- calculate slope of the DEM
- Raster calculator, such that I have a raster that's 0 wherever slope <30%, 1 elsewhere
- SAGA buffer with a distance of 20m (grid resolution) to get a 1 pixel buffer

[image: The DEM with buffered steep parts]

I'd get a boundary around the steep slopes. However, this boundary goes all around the steep parts.

How can I select the cells that are *downslope* the steep part?